# Kotlin class NoClassDefFoundError crash

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I have an existing Android Project that uses the following libs:

1. AutoValue
2. Dagger2
3. RxJava
4. Retrolambda

I am trying to add Kotlin Support so that I can slowly migrate the project over to Kotlin. 
Here is what I have done.

1. Added Kotlin dependency.
2. Converted one of the classes over to Kt class and moved over to `src/main/kotlin/..package..`
3. Added kotlin in source set.
   sourceSets {
       main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
   }
4. When I do a clean build and deploy the app, I get NoClassDefFoundError exception. However, If I deploy again it works just fine. 
   Any suggestions? I do not have any annotation in the class I converted so I did not apply `kapt` plugin.

Note: I am using latest kotlin 1.0.4. Also I have instant run disabled.

Comment: you might want to report this to [the Kotlin issue tracker](http://kotl.in/issue) because it seems more like something that needs triage and potentially reporting as a bug.

Comment: Do you use any generated classes in your new .kt file? Probably in time of kotlin compilation this class isn't exists.

Answer (score 4):

Go to `Files > Settings` and turn off completely `Instant Run`, I mean all checkboxes should be unchecked.

Clean and rebuild project.

Then it should work

**Edit:** As you said that Instant is disabled - using **`protip`** check your configuration and update Gradle and Android Studio if you're not using the latest.

According to this [issue](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/very-annoying-crash-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-kotlinobject/1893/2), changing Gradle plugin version from 2.10 to 2.14.1 may help.

**Protip:**
Use combination Ctrl+Shift+A to find commands like

- `Configure Kotlin in Project`
- `Configure Kotlin Updates`
- `Convert Java File to Kotlin`

Comment: Yeah I have instant run disabled completely and am runing AS 2.2 with build tool version 2.2.0 with gradle 2.14.1.

Comment: change build-tools to 24.0.3

Comment: this issue has since been resolved after using the updated plugin. Also when this happens I just had to clean the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to configure you android studio with kotlin , for this need to add kotlin plugin in android studio, and then need to add dependencies and then convert java classes to kotlin please have look this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DN2EDdycZ3c

Answer (score 0):

Suffix the Kotlin classes with `kt` when calling them from Java.

Otherwise add `@file:JvmName("Utils")` before the package in the Kotlin class if you must call it in java with whatever custom name you wish like `Utils` in this case.

[more details can be found here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html)